# How to call a Freemarker macro with a map as a parameter?

Tags: dictionary, parameters, macros, freemarker

I have been strolling around with this but couldn't find any documentation or example code.

## Introduction:

I have an ftl page that has this key/value map:

- roomType.description["ES"] = "texto"
- roomType.description["EN"] = "some text"
- roomType.description["PT"] = "texto"

## Question:

How to pass the map as a parameter to a freemarker macro?

## Example code:

#### Macro declaration

```
<#macro descriptionMacro firstLang descriptionText>
    <#-- SOME CODE -->
    <textarea>
        <#if descriptionText[firstLang]??>
            ${descriptionText[firstLang]?trim}
        </#if>
    </textarea>
    <#-- SOME OTHER CODE -->
</#macro>
```

#### Macro call (not working)

```
<@descriptionMacro firstLang="es" descriptionText=roomType.description/>
```

Comment: What error do you have ? Do you have a stacktrace or just nothing displayed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I see in your code is that the key in the map are in upper case ("EN", "ES", "PT"), and you try to access a value in the template using a lower case key "es".

Except for that, I don't see any limitation to use a `Map` as parameter.

For example given this map :

```
  Map<String, String> description = new HashMap<>();
  description.put("en", "Some text");
  description.put("es", "Testo");
  description.put("fr", "Texte");

  Map<String, Object> data = newHashMap();
  data.put("description", description);

  Template template = getTemplate();
  Writer out = new StringWriter();
  template.process(data, out);
```

And this template :

```
<#macro printDescription lang data>
    Description = ${data[lang]}
</#macro>
<@printDescription lang="es" data=description />
```

The output is :

```
Description = Testo
```

Comment: You're right about the uppercase. I first thought that was the problem but the actual code doesn't make that mistake... 
I'm using this inside the macro: ${descriptionText[firstLang?upper_case]?trim}
Anyway I rewrote the whole code looking at your example and it worked! Do you know a good freemarker manual?

Comment: Glad it works now ! For the manual, I use http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html. I usually find what I need there.

Comment: I use freemarker in Eclipse. Sometimes portions of code are not painted right (every lines grey). I suspect when that happens the typical yellow-red erros show up. Does that happen to you sometime?

Comment: Yes it does sometimes, but I don't know why. It is quite rare, so It doesn't really bother me.